# Disable Light sensor during call - Android

Tags: android, sensors

When you talk on the phone in Android the light sensor is working. 
If you cover the top left corner of the screen, the display turns black and you can't see anything.

I would like to cancel that feature and I tried working with [Android Sensors](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) and the [Light Sensor](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_LIGHT) but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
 senMgrLight=(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senMgrLight.registerListener(onSensorListener,
            senMgrLight.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sensor you need to work with is the proximity sensor,
try this, this will let you know if the sensor is hidden or not (and it works while your on a call)

```
   SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sm.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                Log.i(TAG,"sensor: " + event.sensor.getName() + ", values: " + Arrays.toString(event.values));

            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                Log.i(TAG,"accuracy change: " + sensor + ", accuracy: " + accuracy);

            }
        }, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the class [`Settings.System`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) to read the [`SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS) and the [`SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE) via getInt() before a call is made. Then I would set new values via setInt(), namely 255 for the brightness and [`SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL) for the mode - which should give constant brightness at maximum amount.

After the call is hung up you can restore the old values you stored before changing the values via setInt() so the user gets back his initial settings. :-)

Don't forget that the mode is only available for Android 2.2 and higher (API level 8), so you will have to use reflection if you want to target older Android versions, too. And of course you will definitely need permissions to write the system settings.

Comment: Not only does the screen get dark, but the buttons stop working too. this is the proximity-sensor "feature" kicking-in to disable accidental touch-events when on a call. Better if we "attack" the cause here rather than patching up the results. eh?

Answer (score 1):

screen off is controlled  by Proxy Sensor, not Light Sensor.
you can remove the register of proxy sensor in Phone app

Answer (score 0):

I bet you will enjoy this app then!!
[**PROXIMITY-SENSOR-OFF.apk**](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/proximity-screen-off_pjwz_download.html)

Regards
CVS@2600Hertz